# How to decode base 64 json image in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an base64 encoded image in JSON format in my database. I want to decode it through a jQuery AJAX request, then I want to print it in my table.

```
$.getJSON('com.example.com', function(data) {
  // console.log(data); 
  $(data).each(function(i, hero) {
    $('#heroesBody').append($("<tr>")
      .append($("<td>").append(hero.MainCategoryId))
      .append($("<td>").append(hero.MainCategoryName))
      .append($("<td>").append(hero.DisplayOrder)))
    // .append($("<td>").base64.decode(hero.ServiceLogo)));
  });
}).done(function() {
  alert("Completed");
}).fail(function(e) {
  console.log('error:');
  console.error(e);
}).always(function() {
  alert("always runs");
});
```

**EDIT**:

If i write this `.append($('<img/>').attr('src', hero.ServiceLogo))` then i am getting

[image]

and here is the encoding.

[image: CHECK THIS LINK]

Comment: Can you post how you data look like maybe it's not DATA URI? You can post it somewhere and create post the link. Or you can show the code how to you write that image into database.

Comment: Please don't delete your original question on edit, put your edit after your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decode the image, if it's DATA URI (have `data:image/jpg;base64` in front) you can just put into image src attribute and it will work.

```
$("<td>").append($('<img/>').attr('src', hero.ServiceLogo));
```

if it's not DATA URI then you can use this:

```
$("<td>").append($('<img/>').attr('src',  'data:image/jpg;base64,' + hero.ServiceLogo);
```

if the image is gif use `image/gif` and if it's png use `image/png`.

You can even make this universal:

```
var url = hero.ServiceLogo;
if (!url.match(/^data:/)) {
   url = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + url;
}
$("<td>").append($('<img/>').attr('src',  + url);
```

Here is Demo:

```js
var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

$('<img/>').attr('src', dataURI).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you will have very big image, you may have error about size of the src attribute, in that case you will need to render the image on canvas, get the blob and use Object URL.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      $("<td>").append($('<img/>').attr('src',  + url);
  });
};
img.src = strDataURI;
```

And as side note, if you want to decode/encode base64 there is pair of functions:

- btoa - string -> base64
- atob - base64 -> string

this will return "foo" `atob(btoa('foo'))`

Comment: How to use atob in my function.Actually Sir in my case iamge is coming from url in base6. How  i will convert into image to display in my table.

Comment: My image is in json from and encoded through base64. Like hero.MainCategoryId . image is hero.ServiceLogi but it is displaying encoded token and i want to display image

Comment: @AbdulMananAli As I said if it's url in base64 you don't need to decode it, just use in as normal url to image with http, it will work the same. But if you want to decode to get the binary data use `atob(hero.ServiceLogo.replace(/^data[^,]+,/, ''))` but with this, you will not be able to display that image.

Comment: If i write this `.append($("<td>").append(hero.ServiceLogo))` then i am getting encoded string

Comment: @AbdulMananAli look at the demo I've added.

Comment: If i write this `.append($('<img/>').attr('src', hero.ServiceLogo))` then corrupted icons is displaying in image cokumn.

Comment: @AbdulMananAli then it's not Data URI you need to show how this data look like, or show how you save that image into db.

Comment: Myimage is saved in DB in blob type. Now i am getting its corrupted image error in table

Comment: @AbdulMananAli you need to show how you get from image that is binary format and how you save it in DB, it don't convert to base64 by magic. You need to write code that will convert it to base64 if you don't do that you don't have base64. How you upload the image from client to server and how you write that image down to DB or you can show the data you get when you put `$('<pre>').html(hero.ServiceLogo).appendTo('body')`

Comment: oPEN THE ABOVE LINK I HAVE EDITED  IN MY QUESTION

Comment: Have you checked that image ?

Comment: $('<pre>').html(hero.ServiceLogo).appendTo('body') IF i wrtie this i am getting encoded string .

Comment: @AbdulMananAli as I said in the answer if you don't have `data:` in front you need to add this, see my answer. I've putted the code that check if there is data and add it to url. you only used `attr('src', hero.ServiceLogo)` and ignored rest of the answer.